# How to boost Elasticsearch results based on another field?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Kinda simple use case but cannot come up with good solution.

Basically I have two indexed fields: content and keywords (keyword tokenizer), where content is a long text field and keywords contain important terms within that content. When I query with some long text, I have to boost those results based on the keywords present in the matching document.

I tried querying the complete text on both content and keywords field, but it is too slow or it throws `too_many_clauses` error for text with more than 40 words.

```
{"query": {
    "match": {
      "keywords": {
        "query": "some long text",
        "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }}
```

Is there any better way? Would percolator work here?

Comment: `match` should bring the documents that have more weight based on your search terms. Are you saying `match` is not working the way it suppose to?

Comment: percolator feels an overkill here, it's used in recommended or promoted search, where some documents you want to promote or recommended irrespective of thier tf/idf or search score. For example, apple want to promote the posts of iPhone11 as its the latest iphone, irrespective of their search score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can relate this to my application, which is similar to Stackoverflow, which consists of question and answers, for a question, there is subject, body, tags etc.

Subject here relates to your keyword indexed field and body relate to your content indexed field. Normally subject contains the important keywords about the post, which is also the case with you.

**Now coming to solution part**,
How we solve it by querying both on subject and body indexed fields but boost subject by a factor of 15, which is configurable.

ES query which we use:

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query" : "this is a test",
      "fields" : [ "subject^15", "message" ] 
    }
  }
}
```

[This](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) ES doc also has a similar example where they are boosting a subject field in multi_match query by a factor of 3.

Let me know if you have any questions.